# Hour in NSDateComponent in 12 or 24h format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

Is the hour component of NSDateComponent in a 12h or 24h format? I cannot find anything about this in the documentation...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's 24 hours, on the gregorian calendar.

Why? The documentation doesn't say it explicitly; however, it does state that the values are for whatever calendar is used. am/pm is just a different notation -- countries using am/pm still have 24 hours per day, they are just writing if differently.

Also, if you look at the available unit constants, you will notice there there is no "am/pm" constant. Again, that's because am/pm is a localized notation, not a property of the gregorian calendar.

EDIT: if you are asking this because you want to output a time in readable form, don't use NSDateComponents -- use NSDateFormatter.